# Поисковая форма на сайте

Tags: php, html

Есть поисковая форма.

```
div style="float: left">
        <form action="" method="post" class="search" style="margin-top: 14px; margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom: 0px">
            <input type="search"  style="height: 26px" name="" placeholder="Поиск" class="input" />
            <input type="submit" name="" value="" class="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Смотрел сервисы поиска google и yandex, там они предлагают свои поисковые формы.
Можно ли как нибудь прикрутить их функционал к данной форме?

Comment: В чем суть вопроса ? Прикрутить можно куда угодно )

Comment: Конечно, да - можно!